# PHP Image Cache - Stop Compression

Tags: php, image, caching

I'm using the following:
http://nielse63.github.io/php-image-cache/

I must say load times are phenomenal, however with their compression method I am losing my transparency.

In defining an image you use the following code:

```
$d = $image->compress('chicago-skyline.png');
```

However I don't see in their documentation anything about NOT compressing, the compressed out image is actually a jpg which is exactly what I do not want.  How can I get around/stop this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);
```

> Check out this [Click](http://apptha.com/blog/how-to-reduce-image-file-size-while-uploading-using-php-code/)